# Not able to use Vendor into CakePHP 2.8 view files

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

I am using CakePHP 2.8.3 and using KoolPHP UI library, which is placed in 
app/Vendor/KoolControls/
app/Vendor/KoolControls/KoolGrid/koolgrid.php
app/Vendor/KoolControls/KoolAjax/koolajax.php

Now in my view file(.ctp) I am doing these to include the Vendor library

```
$koolpath = "Vendor/KoolControls";

App::import('Vendor', 'KoolControls/KoolGrid', array('file' => 'KoolControls/KoolGrid/koolgrid.php'));
App::import('Vendor', 'KoolControls/KoolAjax', array('file' => 'KoolControls/KoolAjax/koolajax.php'));

$ajax = new koolajax();
$ajax->scriptFolder = "$koolpath/KoolAjax";
$grid = new KoolGrid("grid");
```

And the .htaccess file under app looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule Vendor(.*) Vendor$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the .htaccess file under root looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I goto this page it's not loading koolgrid's css file or koolgrid.php file and I am getting 404 error